# Calling protocol extension function from selector

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols, protocol-extension

i have protocol class named MenuDisplayable. This protocol has an extension.

```
protocol MenuDisplayable {}

extension MenuDisplayable where Self: UIViewController {

func showMenu( ) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .Menu)
   let menuVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! MenuVC
   present(menuVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

}
```

When i call "showMenu" function from #selector inside viewController class

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_hamb").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(StorySelectCarouselVC.showMenu) )
```

i get an error like "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'showMenu()' that is not exposed to Objective-C"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `showMenu` method accessible to Objective-C by prefixing it with the `objc` attribute.

```
@objc func showMenu() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When i add "@objc" prefix, i am getting the error below

"@objc" can only be used with members of classes, "@objc" protocols, and concrete extensions of classes